# Eeeek! Display bug with closing questions on mobile site

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, mobile-web

I was trying to close this [question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7401755/stopping-the-facebook-like-dialog-box-flickering-where-it-overlaps-a-google-maps) as an exact duplicate of [this](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7388275/stopping-the-facebook-like-dialog-box-flickering-where-it-overlaps-a-google-maps) (user doesn't realize facebook.stackoverflow.com is same as stackoverflow.com, and I accidently voted to close the older one).  But closing on the mobile site is pretty tough to do with the rendering bugs shown below:

[image] [image]

Also, when you paste in a URL, the vote to close button is still disabled. Forgot to grab a screenshot.

Comment: And yes that screenshot shows I am half way through my close votes by 8:12 am (just from bad Facebook questions), and I woke up at 7:30 am.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should envy, praise or pity you...

Comment: This is a weird one... might be a browser bug, we're looking into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fix for this will go out with the next build, hopefully.

It's a bit of a hack, so we may need to revisit.  Honestly not sure why the CSS for mobile caused that, it's not significantly different from the desktop CSS there.